# C# splitting regex into string array

Tags: c#, regex, arrays, string

Suppose I have a regex like this:

```
@"\b(one|two|three)\b";
```

How can I get all of these "regex items" into a string array? For example, the string array would contain 3 items - one, two and three.

Comment: To confirm: You want a regex that can parse an existing regex?

Comment: Yeah, basically that. But you don't need to answer anymore because I figured it out.

Comment: Would you tell how, to make this question useful to others? Or just remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can use the RegEx.Split method, by specifying a pattern that defines the splitting positions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Match class's Groups property to pick out successfully matched items in the regex.